# dvmAbort in dvmDecodeIndirectRef in GetStringUTFChars

Tags: android, java-native-interface, abort

I developped a android application with jni.
I got a dvmabort in dvmDecodeIndirectRef in GetStringUTFChars.
I got this abort only once.

Why did it happen?
How to fix it?

If someone knows the point, please teach me.

---

Sorry for insufficient information.

This is my code.

```
std::string toStdStr(JNIEnv* env, jstring jstr)
{
 const char* chars = env->GetStringUTFChars(jstr, 0);  //<-dvmAbort

 std::string stdstr;

 if( NULL==chars  ) {

  stdstr = "";                 

 }else{

  stdstr = std::string(chars );                 
  env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(jstr, chars );                

 }

 return stdstr;
}
```

And below is nkd-stack crash dump.

I overwrote private information with xxxxxxxx

```
********** Crash dump: **********
Build fingerprint: 'xxxxxxxx'
pid: xxxxxxxx, tid: xxxxxxxx, name: Thread-78  >>> xxxxxxxx <<<
signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
Stack frame #00  pc xxxxxxxx  /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+12)
Stack frame #01  pc xxxxxxxx  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+48)
Stack frame #02  pc xxxxxxxx  /system/lib/libc.so (raise+10)
Stack frame #03  pc xxxxxxxx  /system/lib/libc.so
Stack frame #04  pc xxxxxxxx  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+4)
Stack frame #05  pc xxxxxxxx  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmAbort+78)
Stack frame #06  pc xxxxxxxx  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmDecodeIndirectRef(Thread*, _jobject*)+146)
Stack frame #07  pc xxxxxxxx  /system/lib/libdvm.so
Stack frame #08  pc xxxxxxxx  /system/vendor/lib/libxxxxxxxx.so toStdStr(_JNIEnv*, _jstring*)+56): Routine _JNIEnv::GetStringUTFChars(_jstring*, unsigned char*) at /home/softdev/opt/android-ndk-r9d/platforms/android-19/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h:879
...
```

Thanks!

---

2015/04/30 add a postscript

I found that the abort called in ReportJniError at 365th line of jni.cpp.

[Cross Reference: /dalvik/vm/Jni.cpp](http://tools.oesf.biz/android-4.4.2_r1.0/xref/dalvik/vm/Jni.cpp#317)

It's default path.
When does it happen?
What are conditions to come here?

Comment: Please include the relevant code that causes the error.

Answer (score 1):

This means that `jstr` was invalid when was passed to `toStdStr`. Try `env->CreateGlobalRef(jstr)` **before** `toStdStr` call. Don't forget to release global reference.